# Pass function parameters to API response in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an API call I am making:

```
function createReferral(referralData: { actionTypeId: number }) {
  referralAxios.post(`/api/ReferralMasters`, {
    appTypeID: referralData.appTypeId,
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(actionTypeId)
  })
}
```

I am getting an error message saying that `actionTypeId` is not defined.

How do I go about passing my function parameter to the `.then` part of the API call?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure what you mean. `number` refers to the type.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter description does not desctructure `actionTypeId` from parameters.
If you would like to destructure, this is the way to do it.

```js
 function createReferral({ actionTypeId, appTypeId }: {actionTypeId: number, appTypeId: number}) {
    referralAxios.post(`/api/ReferralMasters`, {
      appTypeID: appTypeId,

    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(actionTypeId)
      })
  }
```

However, if you would like to simplify, it's best not to destructure, and use interfaces/types for type definition.

```js
interface ReferralInterface {
  actionTypeId: number;
  appTypeId: number;
}

function createReferral(referralData: ReferralInterface) {
   referralAxios.post(`/api/ReferralMasters`, {
     appTypeID: referralData.appTypeId,

   })
     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(referralData.actionTypeId)
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `actionTypeId` is a part of the `referralData` object and therefore not visible to the `then` function. Try to print it the following way instead:

```
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data.actionTypeId);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get that value from `referralData`:

```
function createReferral(referralData: { appTypeId: number, actionTypeId: number }) {
  referralAxios.post(`/api/ReferralMasters`, {
    appTypeID: referralData.appTypeId,
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(referralData.actionTypeId)
  })
}
 
createReferral({ appTypeId: 10, actionTypeId: 20 })
```